# Setup Xcode Server on Remote System using ip address or other alternative

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, osx-server, xcode-server

I want to setup Xcode Server on single system (Mac Mini) and other team members will access that server for CI and CD.
I have successfully implemented on each system individually but i want to make it centralised. It may be a dedicated System or one of the team member's Mac Mini.

Comment: Is there a specific question you're looking to have answered? Have you already setup your single CI/CD machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup multiple Xcode Servers using the "Accounts" tab in the Xcode preferences:

- Xcode Menu > Preferences
- Navigate to the "Accounts" tab
- Click the "+" button
- Select "Xcode Server"
- Enter the information for the shared server.

[image: Xcode 'Accounts' Preferences Page]

Xcode uses several TCP ports outside of HTTPS, including:
20300 and 20343 - 20346.

Comment: Hello Richard, the above answer works in a LAN, but what if the Xcode server runs in the cloud. What are the network ports that we need to open? SSH alone is not enough.

Comment: self answering my comment above : you also need to be sure to open TCP ports 20300 and 20343 - 20346